# Photoswipe can't list all images on page

Tags: jquery, photoswipe

I'm using http://photoswipe.com/ to generate a photo gallery on my website, it works fine, but when I add a div inside the gallery loop, it only show some images.

Here is my HTML code: https://jsfiddle.net/mjuut2um/

I'm setting the gallery parent using:

```
initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.demo-gallery');
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Default init code from [the documentation](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html) is very strict on the markup that you pass, as it doesn't use jQuery.

Modify `parseThumbnailElements` to fit your requirements, every line is self-explanatory, e.g. perform a check if current element is a `figure`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something to do with the extension?